# Sentiment analysis API for public comments

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Please help with the sentiment analysis API for public comments and mining of the same. how to best handle such large comments with the Text Analytics?

Comment: Can you please add more details about the use case that you are trying.

Comment: Please follow the below to detect sentiment analysis using the text analytic API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-sentiment-analysis?tabs=version-3

Answer (score 0):

Opinion mining is a feature of Sentiment Analysis please follow the below for sentiment analysis.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/opinion-mining-is-now-available-in-text-analytics-in-public-preview/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-sentiment-analysis?tabs=version-3#opinion-mining